# How to avoid copy-paste when create similar classes in Java

Tags: java, android

I have created a custom `MyAspectButton` that keeps the aspect:

```
public class MyAspectButton extends Button
{
    private float m_aspect = -1.f;

    // ...
    // ... Constructors, setters/getters ...
    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        if (aspect >= 0.f)
        {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            final int measuredWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
            widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(measuredWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Math.round(measuredWidth * aspect), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        }
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Now I want to have `MyAspectLinearLayout`, `MyAspectRelativeLayout`, and so on. Their `onMeasure` method will be the same.

How can I implement a bunch of these classes with as little copy-paste as possible?

I am aware of a concept of generic classes in Java, but here I would have to inherit from template parameter that compiler does not let me to do:

```
public class MyAspectWidget<T> extends T
{
    // ...
}
```

does not compile.

Comment: just write this measurement logic in standalone static class and use its methods at the `onMeasure`

Comment: @user2418306 this won't work, because OP already has base classes: Button, RelativeLayout, LinearLayout and so on.

Comment: @nikis `AbstractLayoutButton extends Button`, `SpecificLayoutButton extends AbstractLayoutButton`. Explain to me why this won't work?

Comment: @user2418306 and how does it solve the issue? every time in `AbstractLayoutButton`, `AbstractLinearLayout`, `AbstractRelativeLayout` he will have to copy-paste the same measurement code.

Comment: @nikis My bad. I thought OP wants a bunch of buttons for different layouts. Though `Button` and `Layout` are not similar classes, are they?

Comment: @user2418306 They are both children of `View`, so they are :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to inherit from a bunch of different base classes, but apply the same behaviour to all of them:

```
MyAspectButton extends Button
MyAspectLinearLayout extends LinearLayout
MyAspectRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout
```

What you are looking for is multiple inheritance, which Java does not support. Your only option is to have a single class that performs the measuring logic, which each of your child classes' `onMeasure` method call into:

```
public class MyAspectButton extends Button
{
    private float m_aspect = -1.f;

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        super.onMeasure(MyMeasuringClass.MeasureWidth(this, widthMeasureSpec), MyMeasuringClass.MeasureHeight(this, heightMeasureSpec));
    }
}
```

Comment: I also want to read `m_aspect` from attributes in `public MyAspectButton(Context context, AttributeSet set)`. If I undestand you correcly, I will have to copy-paste all this stuff in all the custom classes as well?